# Why remove and rename functions does not work in my program?

Tags: c

When I try to delete a file using the fowling lines of code, I get as result that the both files (stock.dat and clone.dat) exists after the end of the program (as result i want to exist only the renamed stock.dat (=original name was clone.dat)). Thanks in advance.

```
    int code;
    FILE *stock=fopen("stock.dat","rb");
    FILE *stc_clone=fopen("clone.dat","wb");

    printf("PLEASE TYPE THE CODE OF THE PRODUCT YOU WISH TO DELETE:\t");

    scanf(" %d",& code);
    printf("\n");


    fseek(stock,0,SEEK_END);

    int fl_size=ftell(stock);
    int quantity= fl_size/sizeof(product);

    rewind(stock);

    prdct prd_pntr= (product *) malloc(sizeof(product)*quantity);
    assert(prd_pntr);

    fread(prd_pntr,sizeof(product),quantity,stock);

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<quantity;i++){

        if(prd_pntr[i].code==code){

            continue;

        }else{

            fprintf(stc_clone,"%d %s %d",prd_pntr[i].code,prd_pntr[i].description,prd_pntr[i].volume);

        }

    }

    fclose(stc_clone);
    fclose(stock);
    remove(stock);
    rename("clone.dat","stock.dat");
    free(prd_pntr);
    printf("\n\a THE PRODUCT DELETED!!!\n");
```

Comment: You're `remove(stock);` is invoked on a `FILE*`, not the name of the file itself. See [**remove()**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) for the proper usage. The compiler should have warned you of this. Therefore the deletion of the file fails (because you never gave it a file name), therefore the rename fails , therefore you now have two files.

Comment: product isn't defined in your code sample

Comment: ALWAYS do error handling when it comes to files. If you checked what remove returned, you wouldn't have been here asking a question...

Comment: If the compiler warning telling you a `FILE*` is not a `const char*` were investigated, you wouldn't even have to go that far. "Incompatible pointer types passing `'FILE *'` (aka `'struct __sFILE *'`) to parameter of type `'const char *'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not remove the file because you are passing `FILE*` instead of `char*` to the [`remove`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/remove.html) function:

```
FILE *stock = fopen("stock.dat","rb");
...
fclose(stock);
remove(stock); // <<== HERE: you are supposed to pass a name, not FILE*
```

To fix the problem, change the `remove` line as followsL

```
remove("stock.dat");
```